# Caching ElementCriteria Lookups In Craft CMS Plugins

Tags: entries, cache, elementcriteriamodel

Two recent sites I’ve built have plugins built to handle filtering through projects based on some categories and related entries.

For example the lookups look similar to this:

```
# Get element criterea for searching projects
$projectCriterea = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$projectCriterea->section = 'projects';
$projectCriterea->limit = null;
$projectCriterea->relatedTo = $relatedElements; # This is an array of categories and related entries.
$projects = $projectCriterea->find();
```

All these lookups aren’t particularly fast, and there aren’t that many different variants. Is there a way I can add some caching into these lookups?

I had a bit of a look into the [CacheService](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/CacheService) but I'm not sure how to apply that to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out, but am not sure if this is the best way so could still use some advice.

```
# Get a unique hash of your search criteria (still figuring this out).
$hash = md5(json_encode($projectCriterea));

# Look up the cache
$cache = craft()->cache->get($hash);

# Did we find this search criterea in the cache already? If so, return it.
if ($cache) {
    return $cache;
}

# No cache? Do searchy business
# ...
$projects = $projectCriterea->find();
# ...

# Save to the cache
if ($cache === false) {
    craft()->cache->set($hash, $projects, 604800); # Cache for 1 week
}

return $projects;
```